# How does one change a number to letter using a modulus in this program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

Originally, the code outputs combinations without replacement. It can be found at [Combination without replacement C++](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.2B.2B) I added the part that subtracts one from the set when the set is complete. For example, if combinations of 4 from the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} were input the output would be as follows:

comb(N=items chosen from, K=set amount)

comb(N=5, K=4)
~ Output ~

```
0,1,2,3
0,1,2,4
0,1,3,4
0,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

⇓
comb(N=5, K=4-1)
~ Output ~

```
0,1,2
0,1,3
0,1,4
0,2,3
0,2,4
0,3,4
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,4
2,3,4
```

⇓
comb(N=5,K=(4-2) or (3-1))
~ Output ~

```
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
```

⇓
comb(5,K=(4-3) or (2-1))
~ Output ~
END

If one wanted to change the numbers to letters with the numbers in the same order how would one do this with a modulus? Any other ideas regarding how to do this?

My attempt is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1);
    bitmask.resize(N, 0);

    do {
         for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)

               {
                  if (bitmask[i])
                      std::cout << " " << i;
                  if (i == 0 || i%10 == 0)
                     std::cout << " " << "C" << endl;
                  else if (i == 1 || i%10 == 1)
                     std::cout << " " << "C#" << endl;
                  else if (i == 2 || i%10 ==1)
                     std::cout << " " << "D" << endl;

                  //the "else if" statements go up to i == 11 which is B//
               }
       } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
} 
int main()
{
    for (int i = 6; i > 0; i--){
        comb(6,i);
        }
}
```

The output is less than satisfactory.

```
Sound
0C
1C#
2D
3D#
Sound
0C
1C#
2D
D# 
0C
1C#
2D
D#
0C
...
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are required to use a modulus?  Is this a programming challenge?  Or homework?  Or do you just feel like a modulus is the way?

Comment: This is a personal project so I'm not required to do anything in any particular way. I genuinely thought a modulus (moduli?) was an option.   When you think of a better way, and if you want to spill the beans, go ahead.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that when i=0 then i%10=0 and when i=1 then i%10=1. You don't need to do: `(i==1)||(i%10==1)' because if one condition evaluates to true the other will also have to evaluate to true(due to the absurd, awesome, crazy, etc. rules of mathematics).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the classic way to map a `0` through `n` integer to another type is to use an array.

```
const std::string string_map[] =
{
    "C",  // instead of 0
    "C#", // instead of 1
    "D",  // instead of 2
    ....
}
```

Then in the same code, instead of integer `n`, use `string_map[n]`...